# How to improve SQL Server query performance

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

Table Size 32GB 
Row count 250M

Table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    ID [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    server [varchar](50) NULL,
    server_id [int] NOT NULL,
    merchant_id [int] NOT NULL,
    order_id [int] NOT NULL,
    customer_id [int] NOT NULL,
    customer_name [varchar](50) NULL,   
    [amount] [money] NULL,
    order_date [smalldatetime] NULL,
    ship_date [smalldatetime] NULL, 
    order_status [varchar](50) NULL,    
    custom_field_1 [varchar](50) NULL,
    custom_field_2 [varchar](50) NULL,
    custom_field_3 [varchar](50) NULL,
    custom_field_4 [varchar](50) NULL,
    created_at [datetime] NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Orders] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have following non-clustered index

```
merchant_id, order_id
order_date
```

Logically, the `order_id`, `merchant_id` make a unique key.

Simple query like below takes almost 30 minutes.

```
select 
    sum(amount)
from 
    Orders 
where 
    Order_Date >= getdate() - 7
```

I have few questions:

- Is the PK right? Currently it is on ID field and it is not being used for anything.
- Will making `order_id` and `merchant_id` as PK help in performance?
- What are the ideal indexes I should have on this table?

Comment: you should create an index on `Order_Date`, even better if it includes `amount`

Comment: What's the query plan?

Comment: Noticing the size of your table and the row count, you'll probably want to take what SqlZim has suggested and rebuild indexes periodically based on the amount of traffic writing to that table to reduce fragmentation.

Comment: check the table fragmentation, dbcc showcontig() and try with dbreindex / indexdefrag (depends your case).

Answer (score 1):

> Is the PK Right?

Probably. Using this surrogate `id` for the **clustering** key keeps the storage overhead lower for all indexes by using a thin 4 byte key instead of the composite 12 byte key of `merchant_id, order_id, order_date` or 8 byte key of  `merchant_id, order_id`

The clustering key is how each index points back to the rest of the table.

- [The Clustered Index Debate Continues… - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/)
- [More considerations for the clustering key – the clustered index debate continues! - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/more-considerations-for-the-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-continues/)
- [How much does that key cost? (plus sp_helpindex9) - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/how-much-does-that-key-cost-plus-sp_helpindex9/)

> Will making order_id and merchant_id as PK help in performance?

You would have to review the impact on all queries that run against the table to know if it would help or not.

I would focus on evaluating covering indexes for queries that you need to run faster, and if you find a trend where you need those two columns for most of your queries, then maybe.

> What are the ideal indexes I should have on this table?

You need to review the queries, execution plans, and current index usage to be able to determine which indexes you need for that table.

---

Since your `order_date` is not the first column in your nonclustered index, the optimizer will most likely not use it for your example query.

Even if you have an index on `order_date`, it is going to have to go back to the table to get the `amount`. If you include `amount` in as an included column on the index, it will become a covering index for that query, with no need to go back to the table.

For that example query, you could use something like this to have an index-only query, instead of one with a table lookup:

```
create nonclustered index ix_Orders (Order_Date) include (amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is index on date . Create a non clustered index on date it will help in the performance . Indexing is very important in query performance . Jus tto start you should have index on those column which are heavily used in where clause in your case date field .

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to alter the index on Order_Date, make it covering index including Amount column. The same is suggested by @Lamark
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/